# cant pair my bluetooth keyboard because enter button doesnt work

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

can someone help me pair my Bluetooth keyboard? The Enter button is broken or at least doesn't work. So when I try to pair its asking me to type in a pass code then press enter. That doesn't work. I tried using Auto Hot Key to remap enter to shift button but didn't work also. I'm out of ideas can someone help me?

Comment: Can you use a mouse with an on screen keyboard to complete the hook up? Also can you replace the keyboard?

Comment: it doesnt work with on screen keyboard also I dont really want to replace it

Comment: I would at this point run the manufacturer's hardware tests.  Are you saying you get the same keyboard error with on screen as with keyboard? Or that on screen just does not work?

Comment: I cant pair at all with on screen keyboard

Comment: Is there no keyboard *anywhere* that you can plug in to accomplish this?

Comment: yes I have another keyboard but it doesnt work im pretty sure i have to type the passcode with the keyboard im trying to pair

Answer (score 0):

> can someone help me pair my Bluetooth keyboard? The Enter button is
> broken or at least doesn't work.

On Screen keyboard works (so presumably the hardware other than the BT keyboard is fine) but that does not permit the BT keyboard pairing.

So at this point, the only practical repair is to replace the Bluetooth keyboard.

Comment: I think you have to type in the pass code directly on the keyboard youre trying to pair for it to work?

Comment: Yes and so the part not working is the keyboard and so it needs to be replaced.

Comment: is there a way to bypass the passcode?

Comment: I do not think so.  That is a function of the keyboard.

Comment: ok thank you i guess ill buy another 1

Comment: Yes.  Always a pain to replace things like this. I hope you will acknowledge my answer